# factoryboy not working with freezegun

Tags: python, django, django-models, factory-boy, freezegun

simple model(models.py):

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateField()
```

simple factory(test_factories.py):

```
from datetime import date
import factory
from .models import MyModel

class MyModelFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    start_date = date.today()
```

In `manage.py shell`:

```
In [1]: from datetime import date

In [2]: from freezegun import freeze_time

In [3]: from polls.test_factories import MyModelFactory

In [4]: date.today()
Out[4]: datetime.date(2017, 8, 16)

In [5]: with freeze_time(date(1999,9,9)):
   ...:     print(date.today())
   ...:     m = MyModelFactory()
   ...:     print(m.start_date)
   ...: 
1999-09-09
2017-08-16
```

current date is 2017-08-16 and fake date is 1999-09-09. Inside `freeze_time`, `date.today()` give fake date but factoryboy is not affected by freezegun. It still give real current date.

- Is this bug? If yes, bug with factoryboy or freezegun?
- How to solve this? In other words, How to make factoryboy give fake date? (For now, I use `MyModelFactory(start_date=date.today())` to create model   with fake date.)

freezegun version: 0.3.9

factoryboy version: 2.8.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that `date.today()` is evaluated when python parses the factory declaration; and factory_boy only receives the resulting date instance.

This is part of the core Python behavior — and can't be overridden by factory_boy.

The proper solution for this problem would be to use a [`factory.LazyFunction`](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#lazyfunction) declaration:

```
class MyModelFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    # Note that we simply pass a callable.
    start_date = factory.LazyFunction(date.today)
```

You might also want to take a look at [`factory.fuzzy.FuzzyDate`](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fuzzy.html#fuzzydate) which would generate random dates in a given timespan.

Answer (score 3):

`LazyFunction(date.today)` doesn't solve the problem because `date.today` is bound before the time is frozen (`datetime.date` gets overridden with `FakeDate`).

`LazyFunction(lambda: date.today())` does solve the problem because it's evaluated after freezing time.